# Retrieve Blob from Mysql And Display it on JSP

Tags: java

How do i convert blob form mySQL and display it on jsp?
i dont know how to continue after writing this in DAO.
I only recently learned about simple spring mvc.

```
 public List<PhotoResponseDTO> getAllPhoto() throws IOException {
          List<PhotoResponseDTO> photos=new ArrayList<PhotoResponseDTO>(); 
          String sql="SELECT * FROM photot ";
          try {
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()) {
              PhotoResponseDTO photo=new PhotoResponseDTO();
              photo.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
              photo.setImage(rs.getBytes("image"));
              photo.setDate(rs.getString("date"));
                  photos.add(photo);
```

Comment: You can't render blob in JSP, you can save them to a directory, and then map this directory to a webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JSP, you'll probably render some html which looks like this

```html
<img src="/photo/id1.jpg" />
<img src="/photo/id2.jpg" />
<img src="/photo/id3.jpg" />
<img src="/photo/id4.jpg" />
```

You'll then need to have a `@Controller` which is mapped to `/photo/{id}.jpg`  which returns actual image binary for each individual photo. The browser will make multiple requests to `/photo/{id}.jpg` (one for each photo).

So your API will need two separate methods and might look something like

```java
public interface PhotoService {
    /**
     * return a list of meta data for all photos matching the filter, 
     * each object containing id, date, extension etc but NOT the blob
     */
    List<PhotoMeta> getPhotoMetas(PhotoFilter filter);

    /**
     * contains the blob for a single photo plus any response headers (eg Content-Type)
     */
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPhotoResponse(String id);
}
```